# Frustration with decltype of functions

Tags: c++, function, type-traits

I am now writing wrapper for some Windows library functions so I need extract their prototype and write a new wrapper with a modified prototype. For example: the function

```
int recv(SOCKET, char*, int, int)
```

will be wrapped by

```
recv_wrapper(SOCKET, char*, int, int, THREADID)
```

To avoid erroneousness, I write a wrapper template:

```
template <typename F> struct wrapper;

template <typename R, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
struct wrapper<R(T1,T2,T3,T4)> 
{
  typedef R result_type;
  typedef R (type)(T1,T2,T3,T4,THREADID);
};
```

and then the following wrapped type **works**:

```
typedef int recv_t(SOCKET,char*,int,int);
typedef wrapper<recv_t>::type recv_wrapper_t;
```

But I want to go a bit further using decltype to get the type of recv automatically:

```
typedef decltype(recv) recv_t;
typedef wrapper<recv_t>::type recv_wrapper_t;
```

But this **does not work**, I try several ways to modify that but I get always the error from VS2010 compiler:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'wrapper<F>'
with
        [
            F=int (SOCKET,char *,int,int)
        ]
```

and

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'recv_wrapper_t'
```

I am quite frustrated with that because here `F` is nothing but the `recv_t` defined explicitly:

```
typedef int recv_t(SOCKET,char*,int,int);
```

but when get it automatically with `decltype`, it does not work anymore.

Many thanks for any consideration.

N.B. I have fix a typo error following the suggestion of n.m.; but that still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

`template <typename F> wrapper;` is invalid. Did you mean `template <typename F> struct wrapper;`? If you fix this, the obvious syntax works:

```
typedef wrapper<decltype(recv)>::type recv_wrapper_t;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot n.m.. This is my typo error, I mean template <typename F> struct wrapper;